# Zero order term in an expression

Tags: series-expansion

I have a very long expression like `a + b  x/y + f + c y/x + d (x z)/y + ...` where `a , b, c, f ...` are coefficients and `x,y,z,...` are variables. I need to pick up the terms without variables which are `a , f` here how can I do this?

Or even collection of the zero order terms will be helpful.

Comment: Try the `Coefficient` function with the 3rd argument as 0.

Comment: @Nasser, Would you explain how this works? The coefficient `a, b,...` are themselves complicated functions of other variables then what should i put in MemberQ[{...} ?

Comment: @Jonie, and what for second argument?

Comment: @Nasser, suppose zero order terms are complicated functions of other parameters `a=f(i,j,k), ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you can pick all expression at the first level which are free of any of your variables

```
Cases[a + b x/y + f + c y/x + d (x z)/y, _?(FreeQ[#, x | y | z] &)]
```

Equivalently you can use `Select`

```
Select[List @@ (a + b x/y + f + c y/x + d (x z)/y), FreeQ[#, x | y | z] &]
```

Answer (score 3):

In case there are terms like $\frac{(x-1) (x+1)}{x^2-1}$ you may try to simplify the expression and then follow halirutan's solution.

Another approach is to use `Series`.

```
Series[a + b x/y + f + c y/x + d (x z)/y, {x, 0, 0}, {y, 0, 0}, {z, 0,
0}] // Normal
(* a + f *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a refinement of @Suba's idea:

```
SeriesCoefficient[
    a + b x/y + f + c y/x + d (x z)/y,
    {x, 0, 0}, {y, 0, 0}, {z, 0, 0}
]
```

> a + f

This works better than using [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) and [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal), for example:

```
expr = 1/z + b x/y + a;
Series[expr, {x, 0, 0}, {y, 0, 0}, {z, 0, 0}] //Normal

SeriesCoefficient[expr, {x, 0, 0}, {y, 0, 0}, {z, 0, 0}]
```

> a + 1/z
>
> a